# Загрузка ресурсов из .jar файла

Tags: java, jar

У меня в проекте в папке с ресурсами лежит папка с `.xml` файлами

```
src
  -main 
     -resources
         -entity
             entity1.xml
             entity2.xml
```

Названия этих файлов заранее я не знаю и сначала просто закружаю папку `entity` после чего беру из нее список файлов и уже с ними работаю.

```
File dir = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("entity").getFile());
File[] arrFiles = dir.listFiles();
```

И таким образом я получаю список файлов в папке entity.
Все это работает когда я запускаю проект из IDE или с помощью  Gradle, но когда я собираю и запускаю `.jar` то эти ресурсы уже не загружаются.

Нашел примеры где используют

`getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("entity")`

Но результатом будет InputStream  и мне не понятно как можно его преобразовать в файл (папку entity) , что  бы потом взять из него список файлов ?

Comment: Походу то что вам надо http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012819/how-can-i-get-a-resource-folder-from-inside-my-jar-file